# Url refresh after post

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

I am using codeigniter php framework.
Currently I have the php page with form post which is the search form and will remain the same php file after post. This php page has header php file section which has login button.

The form Url likes `http:\\xxxxx.com\$xxx\$aaa\$bbb`.
`$xxx`, `$aaa` and `$bbb` are variables and they are come from previous post.
They will be refreshed after post as these variables will get from the form control selection.

Now there is problem come. If I want to get the `current_url()` after user click login button in the header, it is previous url and cannot get the new url after post.
Is there any solution??

Comment: use pure javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Use [site_url()](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) to get your site URL and then append additional data

Comment: Actually is it possible to assign control value to the href in form tag.

Comment: e.g. <form href="www.xxxx.com\".control1.value."\".control2.value //>

Comment: If you mean the `action` attiribute of form, then yes. You could use `echo form_open($xxx . '/' .$aaa . '/' . $bbb);`

Comment: Then how to assign $xxx=control1.value.

Comment: do we need javascript??

Comment: If you want to update your form URL based on some form input selection without refreshing your page, then yes, you need javascript